# Hours sum of columns

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, summary, hour

I am using this code to save hours but with the use `ShowFooter` property, can I enter the spaces under the columns in total how to have a use code and `summaryitem` format what should it be?

```
connection.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO LogBook (Se,Me)VALUES(,@Se,@Me)", connection);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Se", Convert.ToDateTime(textEdit7.Text).ToString("HH:mm")); 

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Me", Convert.ToDateTime(textEdit8.Text).ToString("HH:mm"));

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();                                                              
connection.Close();
```

[image: GridView]

Comment: What code is required to sum the columns? and summaryitem format

Comment: wait ... do you want to get sum of hours after you have inserted them ?

Comment: certainly..zack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you are done inserting the data in the database , you can simply use a datareader and achieve your goal :

```
int totalhours;
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Se,Me from LogBook",con)
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteREader();
While (dr.Read)
{
 totalhours = totalhours + Convert.ToInt32(dr[0].ToString().Split(':')(0)) + Convert.ToInt32(dr[1].ToString().Split(':')(0));
}
MessageBox.Show(totalhours);
```

Comment: don't you have a more practical way? for example..only when we click on the button then will write the result in to the textedit. I'm use the Devexpress

Comment: yes you can ,just tell me , does `textEdit7.Text` look like : `10:31` or similar ?

Comment: actually there are eleven columns I need to sum up :) Columns names = Se, Me, MultiPilot, TotalTime, NghtCon, IfrCon, Pic, CoPilot, Dual, Instructor, TimeOfSession

Comment: please explain your entire solution in your question and then i might help

Comment: Dear Zack, Just I trying to do sum the "Se" column and "Me" column and results to write it in the textedits. By the simplest method.

Comment: then my previous solution was the simplest... u said u didn't want it :(

Comment: however , re-check my answer... hope it helps you this time

Comment: do you make an example?

Comment: If it sloves your problem,make sure to mark the answer as answer :)

Comment: Dear Zack...The table is underlining. Is it possible to code in Devexpress format?

Comment: i don't undestand , can you clarify a bit more ?

Comment: sorry, toStrings is underlining, what is the reason?

Comment: make sure to mark the answer as answer if it helped :)

Comment: oops, it would be single quote `':'`

Comment: totalhours = totalhours + Convert.ToInt32(dr[8].ToString().Split":"(0)) + Convert.ToInt32(dr[9].ToString().Split":"(0));     again underlines :)

Comment: `Split":"(0))` , it should be `Split(':')(0))` .. u are doing it wrong again